# Add horizontal line in android widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to add a horizontal line bellow all of my TextViews in android app WIDGET xml but I have an issue and for some reason this doesn't work.

Edit: here is my full xml of the widget that i use in my application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/liner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/da"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#B3B2B0"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ti"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: because its a remote view in a widget i suppose there is the problem, in normal MainActivity.class it's ok i use it but when it comes to my widget in AppWidget.class it says problem with displaying the widget...

Comment: can you paste the enclosing XML? It might be an issue with the placement of your view in the heirarchy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that Widgets does not support Views as you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout). In your case, you could replace that View by a LinearLayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget_horizontal_white_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Would you know how to delete the layer programicly updateViews.remove...something like..?

Comment: This should work: `View widget_horizontal_white_bar = view.findViewById(R.id. widget_horizontal_white_bar);
((LinearLayout) widget_horizontal_white_bar.getParent()).removeView(widget_horizontal_white_bar);`

Comment: Or just make the view `INVISIBLE`or `GONE` if you don't want to remove it from the View's three: `((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.widget_horizontal_white_bar)).setVisibility(View.GONE);`